# What portion of the human genome is dedicated to the developement of the fetus?

Tags: genetics, genomes, human-genome

I was thinking about how we don't know the function of a large portion of DNA and I thought maybe it's because it's only used during the development of the fetus

Comment: "Only used during the development of the fetus" fetus dev is pretty important, no? Depends a lot on what you mean by "dedicated to". Not much of the genome is "dedicated to" an artificial human concept. But [this random paper](https://www.pnas.org/doi/10.1073/pnas.0403929101) estimates that in fish (a developmental model similar to humans), 5-10% of genes are not only used in but critical to development. This is a subset, and in humans there's more neural development, and genes != genome, but that's a start. (It's recommended to do a little googling before you ask a question.)

Comment: I'm guessing this question is coming from misunderstanding "junk DNA" etc and not realizing that there is no confusion about any DNA that codes for proteins that could lead to "missing" some because it's only used in development.